# como hacer el cambio de 24 horas a 12 horas colocando am y pm y sacar con foreach

Tags: php, mysql, array, while, foreach

Tengo un programa de reservas, en una tabla tengo 2 campos, uno lo llamo "status" este campo es donde quedan registradas las horas programadas, quedan así: 10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00,14:00, todo funciona perfecto, en el otro campo llamado "hora" con la ayuda de una función, cuando alguien reserva por ejemplo la hora 14:00 esta automáticamente se elimina del campo "status" y se registra en un campo llamado "hora" esto para que la hora ya no salga disponible, todo hasta allí funciona.

Lo que hago luego con un foreach y un while es recorrer los registros desde las 10:00 hasta las 14:00 obviamente cuando pasa por la hora 13:00 me sale reservada. lo que pasa es que las personas la hora militar o 24 horas no la entienden, entonces he tratado de colocar al lado de la hora un am y un pm pero el bucle no lo lee ya que la condición queda como mayor que y menor que, no se como solucionar esto.

````
         
         $resultadohorario=$conexi->prepare($disponiblehorario);
         
         $resultadohorario->execute(array(':codigo' => $codigo));
         
         $resulhorario=$resultadohorario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         
            
                   $horario=array(0=>array(0=>"00:00"),
                                  1=>array(1=>"01:00"), 
                                  2=>array(2=>"02:00"),
                                  3=>array(3=>"03:00"),
                                  4=>array(4=>"04:00"),
                                  5=>array(5=>"05:00"),
                                  6=>array(6=>"06:00"),
                                  7=>array(7=>"07:00"),
                                  8=>array(8=>"08:00"),
                                  9=>array(9=>"09:00"),
                                 10=>array(10=>"10:00"),
                                 11=>array(11=>"11:00"),
                                 12=>array(12=>"12:00"), 
                                 13=>array(13=>"13:00"),
                                 14=>array(14=>"14:00"),
                                 15=>array(15=>"15:00"),
                                 16=>array(16=>"16:00"),
                                 17=>array(17=>"17:00"),
                                 18=>array(18=>"18:00"),
                                 19=>array(19=>"19:00"),
                                 20=>array(20=>"20:00"),
                                 21=>array(21=>"21:00"),
                                 22=>array(22=>"22:00"), 
                                 23=>array(23=>"23:00"));       
               
               $desde=$resuldisponible['lunesdes'];
               $hasta=$resuldisponible['luneshas'];
               
    $nuevoFormato = '';
               
    $inicio = $desde;
    
    $final    = $hasta;
    
//separamos todos los valores de horas separados del campo hora con explode
// separamos todos los datos del campo status

        $cadena = $resulhorario['hora'];
        $horasseparadas = explode(",", $cadena);
        
        $cadena2 = $resulhorario['status'];
        $statusseparados = explode(",", $cadena2);
        
         

     foreach($horario as $grupo) {
         foreach($grupo as $hora) {
                          
                           $nuevoFormato = $hora ;
              
         if   ($nuevoFormato >= $inicio && $nuevoFormato <= $final) {
    
        // seleccionamos los reservados 
        
          $reserva = 0;
          
     while ($reserva <= $horasseparadas[$reserva] or $reserva <= $statusseparados[$reserva] ){
     
      if ($hora == $horasseparadas[$reserva] ) {
     
    echo "<form action='reservas.php' method='POST'>";
 
    echo "<input type='text' name='reserva' value='$hora RESERVADO' <br>";
    
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='codigo' value='$codigo '/>";
    
    echo "</form>";
    
             }//final if dentro while 
        
        // seleccionamos los horarios disponibles   
        
    else  if ($hora == $statusseparados[$reserva])  {       
             
     echo "<form action='reservas.php' method='POST'>";
 
    echo "<input type='text' name='reserva' value='$hora' <br>";
    
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='codigo' value='$codigo '/>";
    
     echo "<input type='submit' name='reservar' value='RESERVAR AHORA'>";
 
    
    echo "</form>";
       }
       
    $reserva++;
    
   
     
        
   }//final del while
   
                  
         } //final Nuevo                          
            
                                                    }//final 2 foreach
                                           }//final 1 foreach
            
            } // final else if activo

            }// final primer if isset ```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tu problema en concreto? La pregunta está planteada de una forma confusa. Yo no me complicaría con formatos en cuanto a guardar los datos, para el usuario puedes presentar las horas de la forma que él las entienda, pero en background manejarías las horas en formato 24 horas simplemente. De todos modos, tratándose de reservas, ¿por qué no trabajas mejor con objetos `DateTime` (incluyen la fecha y la hora). Esto te permitirá guardar todo en una sola columna y manejar con facilidad situaciones complicadas, como ingreso en un día y salida al día siguiente.

Comment: Gracias por leer la pregunta, precisamente el problema esta en que las personas no entienden la hora "militar" es decir las 13 - 14 - 15 etc.. lo que deseo es que esas horas sean cambiadas a 01:00 pm - 02:00 pm - 03:00 pm et.. cuando coloco así en el foreach y en la base de datos no me funciona.....  13=>array(13=>"01:00 pm"),
                                 14=>array(14=>"02:00 pm"), y en el campo en la base de datos coloque igual pero no funciona, funciona perfecto con la hora formato 24.

Comment: Insisto en que en la pregunta no queda expresado con claridad **cuál es el problema y dónde es el problema** (¿es en el código PHP? ¿es en la base de datos?). Tampoco dices nada sobre el contexto... Empecemos por el principio: ¿de qué tipo es la columna en que guardas la fecha y la hora en la base de datos? Supongo que es una columna `DATETIME`. En ese tipo de dato la hora se guarda siempre en formato 24 horas. A partir de ahí, explícanos ahora cuál es el problema. Y si no tienes los datos definidos así en la base de datos, explícanos cómo los tienes definidos y por qué.